# Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function"

Tags: r

I am trying to run a loop that will compile Bureau of Labor Statistics employment data from 2002 to 2010 in one large data frame for multiple Metro Statistical Areas.

When I run the loop, I get the following error and I am not sure why this is occurring. Anyone have any ideas?

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function"
```

Here is my full code for this small project.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(blscrapeR)

msa <- read.delim("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smitty1788/Personal-Website/master/dl/MSA_Codes.txt",
                header = FALSE) %>% 
  rename(area_code = V2, area_text = V3) %>% 
  select(area_code, area_text) %>% 
  mutate(CBSA_ID = substr(area_code, 5, 9))

MSA_LAUS <- data.frame(date = character(),
                       labor_force = numeric(),
                       employment = numeric(),
                       unemployment = numeric(),
                       unemployment_rate = numeric(),
                       CBSA_ID = character(),
                       area_text = character())

for (i in 1:395) {

  labor_force <- paste0("LAU", msa$area_code[i], "06")
  employment <- paste0("LAU", msa$area_code[i], "05")
  unemployment <- paste0("LAU", msa$area_code[i], "04")
  unemployment_rate <- paste0("LAU", msa$area_code[i], "03")

  series_id <- tibble(
    name = c("labor_force", "employment", "unemployment", "unemployment_rate"),
    id = c(labor_force, employment, unemployment, unemployment_rate)
  )


  laus <- bls_api(seriesid = c(labor_force, employment, unemployment, unemployment_rate), 
                  startyear = 2002, endyear = 2010, 
                  registrationKey = **"YOUR BLS API KEY"**) %>%
    mutate(seriesID = as.character(seriesID)) %>% 
    merge(series_id, by.x = 'seriesID', by.y = 'id', all.x = TRUE) %>%
    filter(!is.na(name)) %>% 
    select(year, periodName, name, value) %>% 
    spread(name, value = value) %>% 
    mutate(date = as.Date(paste0(year, " ", periodName, " ", "01"), '%Y %B %d'),
           CBSA_ID = msa$CBSA_ID[i],
           area_text = msa$area_text[i]) %>% 
    select(date, labor_force, employment, unemployment, unemployment_rate, CBSA_ID, area_text)

  MSA_LAUS <- rbind(MSA_LAUS, laus)
  rm(laus)
}
```